# Not Executing CSS3 Transition Out

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Just putting together a simple burger menu animation and have been stumped by the transition effects not executing and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

It's probably something very simple but can't seem to find the correct reference anywhere.

```
.cross span{
    /* Transition Out*/
    transition: transform .15s ease-in-out; /* No Transition */
    transition: width 0s ease-in-out .1s;
    transition: top .15s ease-in-out .2s; 
}

.cross.active span{
    /* Transition In*/
    transition: top .15s ease-in-out; /* No Transition */
    transition: width 0s ease-in-out .1s;
    transition: transform .15s ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

Here is the Codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPoxXW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to separate transitions by commas inside selector rule:

```
.cross span{
    transition: transform .15s ease-in-out,
                width 0s ease-in-out .1s,
                top .15s ease-in-out .2s;
}
.cross.active span{
    transition: top .15s ease-in-out,
                width 0s ease-in-out .1s,
                transform .15s ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRNKzg?editors=1100)